# Which NSDataReadingOptions should be used when reading a local file?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata

When reading a local file with `NSData(contentsOfURL:options:)`, which one is the appropriate reading option?

Also there is a `NSData(contentsOfURL:)` without `NSDataReadingOptions`. Which reading option does it use by default?

For reference the Apple [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSDataReadingOptions).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you use the method:

```
NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path 
                      options:(NSDataReadingOptions)readOptionsMask 
                        error:(NSError * _Nullable *)errorPtr;
```

The appropriate options depends on what you plan to do with the data; as stated in Apple Documentation :

- `NSDataReadingUncached` : A hint indicating the file should not be stored in the file-system caches. (For data being read once and discarded, this option can improve performance.)
- `NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe` : A hint indicating the file should be mapped into virtual memory, if possible and safe.
- `NSDataReadingMappedAlways` : Hint to map the file in if possible. (This takes precedence over `NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe` if both are given.)

Some explanations about mappedFiles : should only be used if the file is guaranteed to exist for the duration of the data object’s existence. It is generally safer to use the `dataWithContentsOfFile:` method.

When using mappedFiles options, the method assumes mapped files are available from the underlying operating system. A mapped file uses virtual memory techniques to avoid copying pages of the file into memory until they are actually needed.

The other method :

```
NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path;
```

Is the equivalent of `dataWithContentsOfFile:options:error` with no options given.

**Conclusion**

If we put this together, you should use :

- `dataWithContentsOfFile:` if you don't have particular needs for your data, or memory usage problems. It is the safer choice.
- `dataWithContentsOfFile:options:error` with `NSDataReadingUncached` option if you will use the data only once
- `dataWithContentsOfFile:options:error` with `NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe` option if you don't want to immediately load the entire file, and you are sure the file will exists during the whole lifetime of the NSData object.
- `dataWithContentsOfFile:options:error` with `NSDataReadingMappedAlways` option - same as above, but less safeguards.

---

Sources :

[Apple Documentation : NSReadingOptions](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdatareadingoptions?language=objc)

[Apple Documentation : dataWithContentsOfFile](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdata/1547226-datawithcontentsoffile?language=objc)

[Apple Documentation : dataWithContentsOfFile:options:error](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdata/1547244-datawithcontentsoffile?language=objc)